# Как нарисовать круг в Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

```
shape_id =canvas.create_oval(10,10,10,10, outline="red", 
    fill="green", width=2)
```

Как задать радиус кругу в канвасе? Насколько я понимаю тут нет такого атрибута.

Comment: постарайся давать вопросам заголовки, отражающие суть проблемы

Comment: Спасибо, буду стараться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

немного математики:

```
canvas.create_oval(x - r, y - r, x + r, y + r )
```

x,y-координаты центра.r-радиус.

Answer (score 3):

Можно сымитировать:

```
radius = 5
center = 10,10 # Первый арг - координата X, вторая Y

canvas.create_oval(center[0] - radius, center[1] - radius,
                   center[0] + radius, center[1] + radius, outline=...)
```