# Как нарисовать в библиотеке Tkinter круг внутри круга

Tags: python, canvas

Не могу понять как нарисовать круг внутри круга. Как так выставить координаты, чтобы он был ровно внутри другого. Пишу сюда, потому что нигде на просторах Инета такого не встречал. Получаеться вот я создаю пять кругов, но вот как бы я не игрался с координатами они у меня пересекаются((( Буду очень благодарен за любой ответ!

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canv = Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, bg="white")
canv.pack()

canv.create_oval((?, ?), (?, ?), width=2)
canv.create_oval((?, ?), (?, ?), width=2)
canv.create_oval((?, ?), (?, ?), width=2)
canv.create_oval((?, ?), (?, ?), width=2)
canv.create_oval((?, ?), (?, ?), width=2)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Вот такая фигура должна выйти]

Comment: "Координаты" овала - это координаты противоположных углов прямоугольника, ограничивающего этот овал. Нарисуйте схематично прямоугольники вокруг кругов, тогда возможно станет понятнее как координаты вычислять.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как нарисовать круг в Tkinter?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1131670)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что принцип понятен:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canv = Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, bg="white")
canv.pack()

canv.create_oval((20, 20), (180, 180), width=2)
canv.create_oval((40, 40), (160, 160), width=2)
canv.create_oval((60, 60), (140, 140), width=2)
canv.create_oval((80, 80), (120, 120), width=2)
canv.create_oval((100, 100), (100, 100), width=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: спасибо большое, теперь я понял)